# Hover on text with sibling selectors

Tags: css, css-selectors, siblings

I'm trying to make a parallel translation with a text in english on the left side and its translation on the right side.

When I hover on a sentence on the right, I want the equivalent sentence in english to be highlighted.

I tried this but it doesn't seems work :

```
<style>
.left, .right {display:inline-block; vertical-align:top; width:450px;text-    align:justify; padding: 5px;}
.a, .b {}
.main {margin: 0 auto; width:1000px;}

.a:hover ~ .b {
    background:beige;
    transition:all 0.3s ease;
}

.b:hover, .a:hover {
    background:beige;
    transition:all 0.3s ease;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="main">

    <div class="left">
        <span class="a">Text in english 1</span>
        <span class="a">Text in english 2</span>
    </div>

    <div class="right">
        <span class="b">Text translated 1</span>
        <span class="b">Text translated 2</span>
    </div>

</div>
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Regards.

Comment: You won't be able to do this with plain CSS alone. You'll need JavaScript.

Comment: The elements would need to share a parent for a logical CSS selector to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jQuery solution](http://jsfiddle.net/8c6ufruy/)

I added `.hover` class in **CSS**

```
.hover {
    background:beige;
}
```

And a bit of **JavaScript** logic:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var left = $('.left span');
  var right = $('.right span');

  left.hover(function() {
      right.eq($(this).index()).toggleClass('hover');
  });


  right.hover(function() {
      left.eq($(this).index()).toggleClass('hover');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you can't acheive this with your markup, it is possible to achieve it with css alone.

You need to create a parent child relationship as here:

```
<div class="row">
<p class="origin">
    Text in English
    <span class="translation">Translated text</span>
</p>
<p class="origin">
    Text in English 2
    <span class="translation">Translated text 2</span>
</p>
<p class="origin">
    Text in English 3
    <span class="translation">Translated text 3</span>
</p>
```

```
.row {
    padding: 20px;
}

.origin {
    text-align: left;
}

.translation {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
}

.origin:hover > .translation {
    color: red;
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/m1d803sq/

Comment: That's not really "with css alone".

Comment: @BoltClock err  there's nothing here but HTML and CSS

Comment: Thank you very much for this alternative @Simon ! This is very helpful !

Answer (score 0):

You should used a js script to do this, like: (using jquery)

```js
$( "span" ).hover(
  function() {
    var index = $(this).index();
    $('.section').each(function(k, v) {         $(v).find('span').eq(index).addClass('active');
    });
  }, function() {
    var index = $(this).index();
    $('.section').each(function(k, v) {         $(v).find('span').eq(index).removeClass('active');
    });
  }
);
```

```css
.section {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.active {
    background:beige;
    transition:all 0.3s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
    <div class="left section">
        <span class="a">Text in english 1</span>
        <span class="a">Text in english 2</span>
    </div>

    <div class="right section">
        <span class="b">Text translated 1</span>
        <span class="b">Text translated 2</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can easiest made a multiple translate section ordering like this.

Comment: Thank you @Pik_at ! This little bit of script is very good and functional !